# Jquery selectbox keyboard navigation

Tags: jquery, keyboard, drop-down-menu, keyboard-navigation

I am busy with a selectbox in a template but i can't get it solved.

If you go to this page [click here](http://www.dreamwire.nl/DreamAdmin/page.html) and look for the selectbox (it's in the forms section) and use the keyboard navigation it's skips some options and i don't know why?!

Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: Where's the code that modifies that standard select box into the styled one?

Comment: Hi Niklas [click here for the js file](http://www.dreamwire.nl/DreamAdmin/js/jquery.sparkbox-select.js)

Comment: appears to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Qker9/ (I just copied the relevant HTML/JS/CSS without modifying anything)

Comment: I see it... it's strange! Here it's working fine to: [click here](http://www.dreamwire.nl/DreamAdmin/)... i have deleted all the javascript code from other plugins but that didn't help on the page in the start post.

Comment: found the problem and a fix, check my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be in that **sbCustomSelect** plugin. It works fine as long as you initiate it once on the page (you can have it applied on multiple elements, they just need to be under one single selector).

Initiating it twice like this:

```
$('.row.heh select').sbCustomSelect();
$('.row.actionbox select').sbCustomSelect();
```

Will make the jumping occur, like can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Qker9/7/

You can get the same functionality by combining them into one single selector and initializing the plugin only once:

```
$('.row.heh select, .row.actionbox select').sbCustomSelect();
```

And the plugin works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/Qker9/8/

Comment: Niklas that was the problem! Thnx mate!